# Allow a user to select where to save an uploaded file

Tags: 6, files, distributions

I have installed an [Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com/), which is based on Drupal 6, but this is a rather general question towards Drupal 6.

In every content type I have an Upload File field which work just fine, but it does not quite meet my requirements. 
I have already defined an directory structure on my server, which I would like to maintain as is. Therefore, the functionality I am trying to achieve is to allow a user, who selects a file to upload from local computer, to be able to select the path where to store it (preferably outside of Drupal installation).

To be able to reach an outside directory I have created an alias to the necessary directory (e.g. `C:\blalbla\  --> localhost/dev`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a text input with select list, allowed values list will be generated with php code reading the directory you created, then using [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) you will save the upload on the select list input.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a taxonomy vocabulary that stores folder names and then use filefield paths to generate the upload path from those taxonomy terms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But this not that I am trying to achieve. Imagine existed hundreds directories with subdirectories. THerefore taxonomy for each one is just imposible nor practical.